# How to avoid duplicate using Mongodb c++

Tags: java, c++, mongodb, qt

I have a unique index in MongoDB to avoid duplicates.

I am trying to convert simple code from java to c ++ 
here is my code to insert documents into MongoDB.
codes are working perfectly but when I try to insert same documents application stop working.

```
     mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{ "mongodb://localhost:27017" } };
     mongocxx::write_concern writeConcern;
     writeConcern.acknowledge_level(mongocxx::write_concern::level(1));

    QFile inputFile(path);
   if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};
        auto collection = conn["TestDB"]["fdevices"];
        QString line = in.readLine();
        std::string utf8_text = line.toUtf8().constData();
        document << "Data" << utf8_text;

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
        }
    inputFile.close();
     }
```

here is the code that I used in java.
in java, i can simply ignore duplicates by using mongoClient.setWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(0, 10)); and continue my loop to next document.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(asList( new ServerAddress(host+":"+port)), 
        singletonList(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(uname.getText(),
        MongoClientOptions.builder().serverSelectionTimeout(2000)
                                                          .build());
        mongoClient.setWriteConcern(new WriteConcern(0, 10));
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dblist.getSelectedValue().toString());
        DBCollection bookCollection = db.getCollection(collectionss.getSelectedValue().toString());
        for (int i = 0; i <sixe; i++) {
            server.prolab.setText("Uploaded files: "+i+" Total files: "+sixe);
            BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("Data",dataList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
            bookCollection.insert(doc);
        }
```

Comment: `writeConcern` has nothing to do with duplicates. If you are receiving `"Duplicate key error"` then that is **wholly** to do with the data you are inserting, and you likely have a problem you need to look at. No "setting" avoids that error. It's true you can set the write concern to effectively "fire and forget", but if you are importing data then that is really not what you should be doing.

Comment: any idea to continue my loop when an error occurs so that if next document is unique in the loop can be inserted.

Comment: You "should" check the error status on write. Duplicate key errors are `E1100` specifically, and whilst you can "skip over" throwing a fatal exception these really should be "logged" at the very least, for the sake of sane data maintenance. Bottom line is if imported data is resulting in duplicate keys, then "someone" really should be looking into that. Being either correct the data source or correct the code process because something is not being done correctly. But don't bury your head in the sand just because you get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not defining writeConcern method correctly, try these codes.

```
mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{ "mongodb://localhost:27017" } };

        bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};
        mongocxx::write_concern writeConcern;
        writeConcern.acknowledge_level(mongocxx::write_concern::level::k_unacknowledged);
        std::chrono::milliseconds timeout = std::chrono::milliseconds(5000);
        auto collection = conn["TestDB"]["fdevices"];
        collection.write_concern(writeConcern);
        conn.write_concern(writeConcern);

 QFile inputFile(path);
 if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
 {
 QTextStream in(&inputFile);
 while (!in.atEnd())
 {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    std::string utf8_text = line.toUtf8().constData();
    document << "Data" << utf8_text;
    collection.insert_one(document.view());
     }
 inputFile.close();
  }
```